# Can not find class org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory in Tomcat7/Ubuntu 12.10? (Possible bug)

Tags: 12.10, java, tomcat

Tomcat7: 7.0.30-0ubuntu1.1

Tomcat 7 has the jar files commons-dbcp.jar and tomcat-dbcp.jar but in tomcat-dbcp.jar, it is the file org.apache.tomcat.**dbcp**.BasicDataSourceFactory class instead of org.apache.tomcat.**dbcp.dbcp**.BasicDataSourceFactory that is looking for.

**root cause**

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Could not create resource factory instance [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory]
    org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:121)
    javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 7):

A solution is given for [this same problem on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712308/ubuntu-tomcat7-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-tomcat-dbcp-dbcp-bas) by modifying the resource tag in conf/context.xml to use `factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"` instead of Tomcat 7 default factory. You can see there the cause of this problem.

The resource tag will look something like (taken from the referenced answer):

```
<Resource name="jdbc/myDataSource"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabase"
    username="username" password="password"
    validationQuery="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MY_TABLE"
    factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory" />
```

Answer (score 3):

The default DataSource factory in tomcat 7 is org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory. This is contained in a jar file which the Debian maintainers don't distribute.

Tomcat 7 now includes another connection pool implementation which can be used instead, but it isn't default.

```
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory
```

We could change the default factory to this that it is already included in the current distribution and so solve this problem.

Ubuntu version: 12.10

tomcat7: 7.0.30-0ubuntu1.1